# SWT Tree with columns - resizing columns by dragging line

Tags: eclipse, swt

I have a multi-column tree that I really don't want to show column headers (they provide no valuable information in my case and make the layout unnecessarily busy). Unfortunately, I really need to have resizable columns.

How can I make the columns resizable by dragging lines between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SWT uses native widgets and this isn't native behavior (at least on platforms that I am familiar with), so there is no built-in mechanism in SWT for doing what you are after. You should be able to simulate this yourself by tracking mouse events, managing the mouse cursor and calling TreeColumn.setWidth() when appropriate.

Comment: Yes, I started sketching the code - after I confirmed it work neither on GTK nor on Cocoa. It just stroke me as weird as I expected this to be very natural behavior.